# golang casting to void type

Tags: go, casting, void

I know that **void functions** in go are written without mentioning it:

```
func foo(start int, end int) { ... }
```

What about the notion of **casting to void** in C, to emphasize returned value is not used:

```
(void) printf("hello world");
```

does this notion (or equivalent) exist in go?

Comment: You can discard return values by using `_` (the blank identifier) as the target of the assignment. e.g. `_, _ = fmt.Printf("hello world")` (note that `fmt.Printf` returns two values, that's why the two blank identifiers). https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What is it you want to solve?

Comment: I mostly use it as self-documentation. emphasizing that the returned value is not used.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom just be careful not to use the blank identifier, or completely omit the assignment statement with functions that return values that hold references to resources that need to be explicitly cleaned up or closed, otherwise you'll be leaking stuff.

Comment: (Nit-picking): C does not have "void functions", and Go has no type casting. It's not that me being smart-ass or something—just a note to a casual reader.

Comment: @kostix void functions == functions that has void as their return type. they sure exist in C.

Comment: @mkopriva if I understand you correctly, the assignment to the blank identifier `_` can be in some circumstances completely necessary right? not just as a way to comment "this-value-is-not-needed"

Comment: @OrenIshShalom no, what I meant was that using `F()` or `_ = F()` will cause leaks if `F` returns a resource that needs to be explicitly released. In those case you MUST use `v := F()` and then, for example, `v.Release()` to ensure you're not leaking the resource.

Comment: Assignment to a blank identifier is only "necessary" if your function returns multiple values, and you only want a subset of them.  It can also be made "necessary" if you're using a linter that complains if you ignore errors. In that case, explicitly ignoring an error with a blank identifier will make the linter happy.

Comment: OK thanks, I see. I still think a -3 downvote is a bit drastic and the question is in place, but ok.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom for example [`(*sql.DB).Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.3#DB.Query) returns an `*sql.Rows` instance that should be [closed](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.3#Rows.Close) explicitly, if it isn't then the underlying connection will leak. And it's similar with [`(*sql.DB).QueryRow`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.3#DB.QueryRow) which returns an `*sql.Row` that needs to have its [`Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.3#Row.Scan) method invoked, if you omit that then it will also leak the underlying connection.

Comment: «void functions == functions that has void as their return type. they sure exist in C.». Functions which have void as their return type surely exist, but there's no "void functions" in the C standard; you could try to find this term in the texts of [the published standards of C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#9899). That's precisely what I wanted to highlight: you're free to use whatever words you want but such choices might have nothing to do with the relevant standards. (And that's why "nit-picking".)

Comment: I can guess the downvoters imply such questions are typically answered by introductory-level materials such as ["Effective Go"](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#blank). IoW it's a textbook question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go doesn't support type casting, and Go doesn't have any void type, so there's no functional equivalent to what you're asking for.

For the purpose of documenting that you're intentionally ignoring the return value of a function that returns something, you can use the blank identifier, which simply discards the value:

```golang
_, _ = fmt.Printf("Hello world")
```

Answer (score 3):

> [D] oes this notion (or equivalent) exist in go?

No.